# Non-static method PDO::quote() cannot be called statically,

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, passwords

[image: Error i get from WAMP]

```
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];


 $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_DATABASE.'', ''.$DB_USER.'', ''.$DB_PASSWORD.'');

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
$query->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$row_count = $query->rowCount();
```

Trying to do a simple username and PW check from an database..
I'm beyond the point of frustrated...

Comment: Your question-title and your actual question are different.

Comment: Your title and error screenshot tell two different things by the way.

Comment: You're using `query` when you should be using `prepare`.

Comment: And as per this *Non-static method PDO::quote() cannot be called statically...*, it seems `quote()` is an instance method and you're trying to call it from the class itself. First create an object, and then call it's method `quote()`.

Comment: @JonStirling Because you pointed out the error in the comment itself, hence my subsequent comment, in case OP might find it useful. :-)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Aye. I jumped the gun a bit on that one ;)

Comment: Noticed the title, haha, solved anyway! Thanks for all the answers-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use prepare instead.

```
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_DATABASE.'', ''.$DB_USER.'', ''.$DB_PASSWORD.'');

$query = "SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE username=:username AND password=:password";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);


$statement->execute();
$row_count = $statement->rowCount();

echo $row_count;
```

More info [**here**](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the first result if you Google the error in the title, here is how to fix the `PDO::quote()` issue.

If you have a PDO instance/connection running, simply connect to that.

```
//PDO::quote();
$pdo->quote();
```

If you are working with the DB, you should be setting the connection at the top of your file, so this should not be a problem.

If you need similar functionality without a PDO connection, you can use the following function.

```
function escape($value) {
    $search =  ["\\",   "\x00", "\n",  "\r",  "'",  '"', "\x1a"];
    $replace = ["\\\\", "\\0",  "\\n", "\\r", "\'", '\"', "\\Z"];

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $value);
}
```

Alternatively you could use something like this, though you'd need to use [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to undo depending on your use case:

```
function escape($value) {
    return strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($value));
}
```

Or just mix and match the two. Though that might yield some unexpected results since there would be overlap.

Answer (score 1):

check it out with below code...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
    $stmt->bindValue(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
```

for pdo $stmt is supported via $db->prepare("sql") not a query. Then you can bind params to the prepared statement and execute it.